# iOS - How to use a small view in different view controllers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, progress-bar

I have a progress bar (with its own controller). This bar is supposed to be shown in different views depending on which view is visible. As the progress will be same, If possible I don't want to create many progress bar in many views rather I want to use same instance in all these views. Also in that way when I need to change any property of the progress bar it will be reflected commonly, which is required.

Please suggest me how can I use this common view. And also if my strategy is wrong, what would be the better design for such scenarios.

Comment: Create a class for declaring progress bar and add  progress bar to the superview. So when ever a change occurs in view controller , progress bar remains in the same position

Comment: I dont know why this question was downvoted? can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Well you have 2 options. You can declare a new Class `ViewBox` (or whatever name) and then use that inside your code

First View Controller

```
 var box:ViewBox = ViewBox()
```

When you segue or transition to your next screen, you can have a predefined variable `var box:ViewBox!`. Then say when you press a button, the button has a function called `transition.`

```
//Now setup the transition inside the Storyboard and name the identifier "toThirdViewController"
override func prepareForSegue(segue:UIStoryboardSegue, sender:AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "toThirdViewController") {
        var vc = segue.destinationViewController as! `nextViewController` //The class of your next viewcontroller goes here
        vc.box = self.box
    }
    //Since The SecondViewController doesn't need ViewBox, we don't need it there.
}
```

where

```
nextViewController:UIViewController {
    var box:ViewBox!
}
```

Or you could do a much simpler way and that is to look up a `UIPageViewController` :)

Comment: When the views are from different storyboards, there is no any direct redirection, how do I handle it? For example, for transition sequence, viewA -> viewB -> viewC and I need to show viewBox only in viewA and viewC.

Comment: Could you clarify this a tad more? "When the views are from different storyboards, there is no direct redirection"

Comment: Lets say, I am showing viewBox in viewA, then I go to viewB where I don't need to show viewBox. Then again I go to viewC where I need to show it again. Other scenario could be I exit viewA and then from parent view I go to viewC. How can I handle those scenarios.

Comment: Is this transition between views happening in Storyboard?

Comment: Yes the transition can be within single storyboard or different @impression7vx